# How do I do a lookup based on the results of a previous lookup in the pipeline?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, pipeline

I am having a hard time trying to get the lookup from the results of the previous lookup

How can I do a lookup from a previous lookup ?

**Schema**

Event gift describes a gift that is given for a particular event:

This is the schema for event gift:

```
const EventGiftSchema = new Schema({
  REF_EventID: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, required: true },
});
```

Event describes the event

Here is the schema for the event

```
const EventSchema = new Schema({
  name: { type: String, required: true },
  REF_EventTypeID: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, required: true },
});
```

the event type defines what type of event it is
here is the schema for the event type:

```
const EventTypeSchema = new Schema({
  name: { type: String, required: true },
  value: { type: Number, required: true },
});
```

**Data**

Here is data for event gift

```
{
  "_id": "61d1e8bdc742575b38a15536",
  "REF_EventID": "61d1e844c742575b38a15526"
}
```

Here is data for Event:

```
{
  "_id": "61d1e844c742575b38a15526" ,
  "name": "Christmas",
  "REF_EventTypeID": "61d1e756c742575b38a15517",
}
```

Here is data for event type

```
{
  "_id": "61d1e756c742575b38a15517",
  "name": "Every Year",
  "value": "1",
}
```

here is what I doing in node js (without the EventType)

```
  var agg_match = {
    $match: {}, // get everything
  };

 // this does the lookup on event document
  var agg_lookup_event = {
    $lookup: {
      from: 'events',
      localField: 'REF_EventID',
      foreignField: '_id',
      as: 'event',
    },
  };

  // this fills in all the event data
  var agg_unwind_event = {
    $unwind: {
      path: '$event',
      preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true,
    },
  };

  var agg_sort = {
    $sort: {
      'event.dateBeg': 1,
      'gift.searchableName': 1,
    },
  };

  var agg = [agg_match, agg_lookup_event, agg_unwind_event];
  var myAggregate = EventGifts.aggregate(agg);

  // I am using mongoose-aggregate-paginate-v2 on my schema... but the pipeline should not be affected.

  var ret = await EventGifts.aggregatePaginate(myAggregate);
```

I have tried adding this:

```
  // this does the lookup on eventtype document
  var agg_lookup_eventtype = {
    $lookup: {
      from: 'eventtypes',
      localField: 'event.REF_EventTypeID',
      foreignField: '_id',
      as: 'eventtype',
    },
  };

  // this fills in all the eventtype data
  var agg_unwind_eventtype = {
    $unwind: {
      path: '$eventtype',
      preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true,
    },
  };
```

then modifying the pipeline

```
  var agg = [
    agg_match,
    agg_lookup_event,
    agg_unwind_event,
    agg_lookup_eventtype,
    agg_unwind_eventtype,
  ];
```

which leaves the REF_EventTypeID in the output - which I don't want.

```
{
  "_id": "61d1e844c742575b38a15526",
  "name": "Christmas",
  "REF_EventTypeID": "61d1e756c742575b38a15517",
}
```

This is what I want is

```
{
  "_id": "61d1e8c2c742575b38a15536",
  "event": {
    "_id": "61d1e844c742575b38a15526",
    "name": "Christmas",
    "eventtype": {
      "_id": "61d1e756c742575b38a15517",
      "name": "Every Year",
      "value": "1"
    }
  }
}
```

***ANSWER***

I figured it out

```
[
  {
    '$lookup': {
      'from': 'events', 
      'localField': 'REF_EventID', 
      'foreignField': '_id', 
      'as': 'event'
    }
  }, {
    '$unwind': {
      'path': '$event', 
      'preserveNullAndEmptyArrays': true
    }
  }, {
    '$lookup': {
      'from': 'eventtypes', 
      'localField': 'event.REF_EventTypeID', 
      'foreignField': '_id', 
      'as': 'eventtype'
    }
  }, {
    '$unwind': {
      'path': '$eventtype', 
      'preserveNullAndEmptyArrays': true
    }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this on for size; it is the lookup-within-lookup made possible by the more advanced `$lookup` API (introduced in 4.0).  It avoids doing an `$unwind`.

```
var r = [
    { _id:"G0", REF_EventID:"E0"}
];
db.Xgift.insert(r);

var r = [
    { _id:"E0", name:"Christmas", REF_EventTypeID: "T1"},
    { _id:"E1", name:"New Years", REF_EventTypeID: "T1"},
    { _id:"E2", name:"Solstice", REF_EventTypeID: "T2"}
];
db.Xevent.insert(r);

var r = [
    { _id:"T1", name:"Every Year", value:1}
];
db.XeventType.insert(r);

c = db.Xgift.aggregate([
    {$lookup: {"from": "Xevent",
               let: { eid: "$REF_EventID" },
               pipeline: [
                   {$match: {$expr: {$eq: [ "$_id", "$$eid" ]} }},
                   {$lookup: {"from": "XeventType",
                              let: { etid: "$REF_EventTypeID" },
                              pipeline: [
                                  {$match: {$expr: {$eq: [ "$_id", "$$etid" ]} }}
                              ],
                              as: "REF_EventTypeID" // replace orig fld with lookup info            
                             }},
                   // event->evenType is 1:1 so "lift" array[0] out:                                
                   {$addFields: {REF_EventTypeID: {$arrayElemAt: ["$REF_EventTypeID",0]}} }
               ],
               as: "REF_EventID"
              }}
    // we know event is 1:1 so "lift" array[0] out and                                              
    // make it the only single object:                                                              
    ,{$addFields: {REF_EventID: {$arrayElemAt: ["$REF_EventID",0]}} }

]);

{
    "_id" : "G0",
    "REF_EventID" : {
        "_id" : "E0",
        "name" : "Christmas",
        "REF_EventTypeID" : {
            "_id" : "T1",
            "name" : "Every Year",
            "value" : 1
        }
    }
}
```

This is a "minimal" stage approach that uses overwrite of existing fields to keep the pipeline tight.  If you really want the field to be named `event` for example, then you would have to add additional `{$unset: "$oldfieldname"}` stages to the `$lookup` pipeline.

Comment: I like it ! I need to upgrade to 4.0 !

Answer (score 0):

```
[
  {
    '$lookup': {
      'from': 'events', 
      'localField': 'REF_EventID', 
      'foreignField': '_id', 
      'as': 'event'
    }
  }, {
    '$unwind': {
      'path': '$event', 
      'preserveNullAndEmptyArrays': true
    }
  }, {
    '$lookup': {
      'from': 'eventtypes', 
      'localField': 'event.REF_EventTypeID', 
      'foreignField': '_id', 
      'as': 'eventtype'
    }
  }, {
    '$unwind': {
      'path': '$eventtype', 
      'preserveNullAndEmptyArrays': true
    }
  }
]
```